# Installing Salesforce apps via code

Tags: salesforce, force.com, salesforce-service-cloud

I am interested to install our "Connected" Salesforce app to customer's Salesforce setup when they run our product's installer.

Is this functionality exposed via an API or any other mechanism?
Or is this something the Salesforce admin must do him / herself?

Thanks a lot for looking into this :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not exposed in the API. Personally, I wouldn't want a 3rd party app installing anything on my Salesforce account without my express permission. Exposing it via the API would allow circumventing the approval process.